# My ajax POST is not being sent to my servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, tomcat, servlets

I've been studying a lot about servlets and I've created one that should receive some positions from my web app, but due to my lack of experience with servlets I have no idea on how to fix it. Plus I don't know where I should put my HTML app anyway, I've heard that it should be in the WebContent folder, and there it is, but it doesn't work. Could you help me?


**UPDATE**: I'm trying to upload some information that will be transformed by my servlet into a `txt` file, to avoid uploading a file per say: "...**I've created one that should receive some positions from my web app**..."


**Server: Apache Tomcat 7.0**

**Eclipse EE Mars**

Thanks in advance.

**My whole project is here: [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6ubfj633zqvfn2f/AAAFJmf_epGQU-GEN47X1l9Sa?dl=0)**

P.S.: I posted the snippet below only for observation, but I can't use script because I don't own the businesses where the libraries are, if you want to see it check it on the link above this PostScript.

**My HTML with AJAX**

```
<body>
  <div id="navgrid">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="tree1">
      <ul class="jqtree_common jqtree-tree">
        <li class="jqtree_common jqtree-folder">
          <div class="jqtree-element jqtree_common"><a class="jqtree_common jqtree-toggler">â–¼</a><span class="jqtree_common jqtree-title jqtree-title-folder">node1</span>
          </div>
          <ul class="jqtree_common ">
            <li class="jqtree_common">
              <div class="jqtree-element jqtree_common"><span class="jqtree-title jqtree_common">child1</span>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="jqtree_common">
              <div class="jqtree-element jqtree_common"><span class="jqtree-title jqtree_common">child2</span>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="jqtree_common jqtree-folder">
          <div class="jqtree-element jqtree_common"><a class="jqtree_common jqtree-toggler">â–¼</a><span class="jqtree_common jqtree-title jqtree-title-folder">node2</span>
          </div>
          <ul class="jqtree_common ">
            <li class="jqtree_common">
              <div class="jqtree-element jqtree_common"><span class="jqtree-title jqtree_common">child3</span>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var POSITIONS;

      //var data is a dynamic JSON file that should be created in the backend.
      var data = [{
        label: 'node1',
        id: 1,
        children: [{
          label: 'child1',
          id: 2
        }, {
          label: 'child2',
          id: 3
        }]
      }, {
        label: 'node2',
        id: 4,
        children: [{
          label: 'child3',
          id: 5
        }]
      }];
      $('#tree1').tree({
        data: data,
        autoOpen: true,
        dragAndDrop: true
      });


      console.log($('#tree1').tree('toJson')); //This will give you the loading jqtree structure.

      $('#tree1').bind(
        'tree.move',
        function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          // do the move first, and _then_ POST back.
          event.move_info.do_move();
          console.log($(this).tree('toJson')); //this will give you the latest tree.
          POSITIONS = $(this).tree('toJson');
          alert(POSITIONS);
          $.post('http://sistema.agrosys.com.br/sistema/labs/CSS_HTML/', {
            tree: $(this).tree('toJson')
          });
          alert("done"); //this will post the json of the latest tree structure.
        }
      );

      var data = new FormData();
      data.append("JqTree", POSITIONS);
      alert('Sending: ' + POSITIONS);
      $.ajax({
        url: '/JqTree',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response) {
          alert("file has been successfully sent\n\n" + POSITIONS);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>
```

**My Servlet**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public Hello() {}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

    out.print("<html><body>");
    out.print("<h3>Hello Servlet</h3>");
    out.print("</body></html>");
}

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     String position = request.getParameter("JqTree");

     PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Positions.txt", "UTF-8");
     writer.println(position);
     writer.close();
}

}
```

**and my web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>JqTree</display-name>


<welcome-file-list>


<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>    
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>    
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>

<description></description>

<display-name>Hello</display-name>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Hello</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: You should really give here the smallest amount of code sufficient to reproduce the issue, for example all the style declarations are not useful. The most obvious point to look at is the url of your ajax call. Is that correct? Can you check in the server access logs if a call is made?

Comment: @JPMoresmau okay, I will fix it right now.

Comment: @JPMoresmau Fixed ;), hope it's neater and clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your AJAX call to

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/JqTree/Hello',
```

where `/JqTree` is the context root of your web app, plus `/Hello` which is the `<url-pattern>` configured for your `Hello` Servlet in your `/WEB-INF/web.xml` file.

---

1. Your `$.ajax()` call is using `post` so you must remember that only `doPost()` would get called.
2. Your `doPost()` doesn't return any output yet your `$.ajax()` call expects a `dataType: 'json'` back. This at times can cause the request to fail silently.
3. I believe you're trying to upload files. If yes, you can't just read the file contents using `request.getParameter()`. You have to write your Servlet code differently to process `multipart/form-data` which varies whether you're running under a Servlet 3.0 or 2.x container.

Comment: your answer is really concise +1,  However, I got a little doubt to solve, Is the rest such as the servlet correct and functional?

Comment: I meant the **web.xml** and **Hello.java** files, are they correct? and Do I need to add something else? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Calne Added my response to your comments as an update.

Comment: Thanks Ravi for being so helpful :)